# How to find the bigger increased value in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a history table

```
user  | point | date 
john  | 100   | 2015-01-01 
smith | 90    | 2015-01-01 
adam  | 95    | 2015-01-01 
john  | 120   | 2015-01-02 
smith | 115   | 2015-01-02 
adam  | 105   | 2015-01-02
john  | 125   | 2015-01-03 
smith | 120   | 2015-01-03 
adam  | 135   | 2015-01-03
```

In this table I want to find the list of users sorted by increased point in last 3 day of the table so the output will be:

```
adam  | 40
smith | 30
john  | 25
```

How can I do that with php and mysql?

Comment: `select max(point) - min(point) AS diff ... group by user order by diff`, basically.

Comment: @MarcB That will only work if points always increase.

Comment: @Barmar I think it will still work even if there is no increase in point because it will always return a value (except if all rows are null). so if there is no change. diff would be 0.

Comment: @Arzgethalm What if it's 10 on 2015-01-01, 20 on 2015-01-02, and goes back go 10 on 2015-01-01. `max-min` will return `10`, but it should be `0`.

Comment: @Barmar Well, I didn't consider that one out. (decrease). it would be better to handle that also, I guess you're right.

Comment: @Barmar  and arzgethalm thx for all answers, but btw if  the point is never decrease which query have best performance ?

Comment: Matching specific rows should be a little better than calculating min and max.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use a self-join of the table, specifying the starting and ending dates.

```
SELECT t1.user, t1.point - t2.point AS diff
FROM yourTable AS t1
JOIN yourTable AS t2 ON t1.user = t2.user
WHERE t1.date = '2015-01-03'
AND t2.date = '2015-01-01'
ORDER BY diff DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this in MySQL alone.

```
select user,(max(point) - min(point)) diff
from your_table
where date > ( CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 DAY )
group by user
order by diff desc
```